# Calling Python from Maven in a Cygwin shell

Tags: python, maven, cygwin

When building with Maven from a Cygwin shell (bash on Windows via Cygwin), the path to /usr/bin is not resolving properly.

Let me explain.  Cygwin comes with Python, which is accessible as a symlink from /usr/bin.  This symlink should be accessible to Maven, because its location is in the PATH environment variable.  Cygwin adds /usr/bin to the PATH environment variable.  However, Maven is unable to find Python.  E.g.

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec (default) on project cloud-devcloud: Command execution failed. Cannot run program "python" (in directory "C:\cygwin\home\myuser\incubator-cloudstack\tools\devcloud"): CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

But Python is there:

```
$ which python
/usr/bin/python
```

Albeit as a symlink.

```
$ ls -al /usr/bin/python
lrwxrwxrwx 1 donall Domain Users 13 Sep 19 11:38 /usr/bin/python -> python2.6.exe
```

Is the issue that Python is a symlink?  Or that Maven cannot access files in /usr/bin?

Answer (score 3):

It seems like maven is running as a regular Windows-native application, not a "cygwin-aware application" (if such thing exists :-) )

This is indicated by the path used internally, which is printed in the log: C:\cygwin\home\myuser\incubator-cloudstack\tools\devcloud

For this reason the call from Maven will not recognize the cygwin path when locating the python executable. One possible solution is to add the directory containing python.exe to the system PATH (which means, the Windows PATH variable)

Comment: Are you sure?  I copied python26.exe over the symlink, and the script worked.  That suggests that the path is fine.

Comment: That was the solution for a related problem that I had, with other programs. I'm not absolutely sure about how Maven handle that call, but the situation is very similar. Anyway, I apologize if the information is inaccurate!